# MYSQL: How to split left join results in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, select, join, rows

I have some data in a table like so:

**user**

```
user_id  name
1        John
2        William
3        cindy
4        Julian
5        Monique
```

**books out**

```
user_id  book_id
1        1
2        3
3        5
5        10
```

**vinyl out**

```
user_id  vinyl_id
1        6
2        7
3        8
4        9
```

I want a single SELECT statement that would produce this output:

```
user_id  item_out
1        1 
1        6
2        3
2        7
3        5     
3        8 
4        9
5        10
```

So, in order of user_id and book_id/vinyl_id. Is this possible?

Comment: You could LEFT JOIN both tables and check with IFNULL() what id to display. Keep one thing in mind, if the same id is in both tables, you won;t see if it is vinyl or a book.

Comment: if i were you i would restructure the database while you still can. make one table `product out` and add a enum column for type. The structure you're using now seems flawed, especially because they seem to be sharing the same id (they have to be unique)

Comment: @Jester This example isn't my real production problem, only a simplified example. Restructuring the database isn't that easy and more complex in my real database. But you are right. I should think about how to restructure this component.

Comment: @johan Both tables doe have the same id. For now I solved this by adding an extra column with a default value for books and vinyl in the select statement. Long term solution would be to restructure the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `UNION ALL` results from two separate queries:

```
SELECT u.user_id, book_id AS item_out
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN books_out AS b ON u.user_id = b.user_id

UNION ALL

SELECT u.user_id, vinyl_id AS item_out
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN vinyl_out AS v ON u.user_id = v.user_id
ORDER BY user_id, item_out
```

The first query returns results from `books_out` table, whereas the second returns results from `vinyl_out` table.

**Note:** `ORDER BY` clause is applied to the result set that is produced by the `UNION ALL` operation.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9f6b9/4)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. First time ever I (need to) use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
Please comment if any error.

```
select u.user_id,b.book_id as item_out from user u left join 
 books_out b on u.user_id = b.user_id 
 UNION ALL
 select u.user_id,v.vinyl_id as item_out from user u left join 
 vinyl_out v on u.user_id = v.user_id 
 order by user_id;
```